# Get array of all plans of Stripe in Golang

Tags: php, go, stripe-connect

I am trying to get list of all plans that exist in my Stripe account using Stripes's Golang API. As per documentation provided here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/go#list_plans it should return a list of all plans. But its returning me only a single plan details.

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go"
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/plan"

)
func main(){
    router := gin.Default()
    stripe.Key = "stripe_api_key"

    router.GET("/plans", func(c *gin.Context) {
        plans := GetAllPlans()
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{  "plans": plans, })
    })
    router.Run(":8080")
}

func GetAllPlans() (plans *stripe.Plan){
    plans = &stripe.Plan{}
    params := &stripe.PlanListParams{}

    it := plan.List(params)
    for it.Next() {         
        plans = it.Plan()
    }
    return 
}
```

What's interesting I have found is the response example provided in the documentation for Golang is somewhat different from other languages like PHP, Ruby etc. For languages other than Go and .NET its returning an array of plans but for Go and .NET its returning a single plan. So I am not sure it is api's default behaviour or some bug.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `plans = it.Plan()` overwrites your `plans` variable. `plans` should be slice of `Plan`s or something like that.

Comment: Yes it should be a slice of plans. Infact I tried making a slice of plans and then did asignment but the api environment did not let me do this. It gave an error about type mismatch.

Comment: Please provide your attempt with slice of plans and error text.

Comment: @u_mulder You were right. There should be a slice of plans. The problem was I was declaring a structure instance but I needed to declare an interface variable to handle slice. However the problem is solved now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If problem solved - you can write your own answer to help people in future.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I found the answer to my question:

I should use a interface instead of structure instance:

```
func GetAllPlans() (interface{}){
    var plans []interface{}
    params := &stripe.PlanListParams{}

    it := plan.List(params)
    for it.Next() {         
        plans = append(plans, it.Plan())
    }
    return plans
}
```

Thanks @u_mulder for a useful hint!